# How to create horizontal histogram in Python's plotnine?

Tags: python, histogram, plotnine

I'm using `plotnine` recently and wanted to plot a horizontal histogram (i.e., a histogram with horizontal bars).

The following example illustrates the vertical histogram:

```
from plotnine import *
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': np.random.normal(0,10,1000), 'group': ['a']*500 + ['b']*500})
# 
(
    ggplot(df, aes(x = 'values', y = after_stat('count'), fill = 'group'))
    + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)
)
```

And the result:

[image]

Simply changing the axes in `aes` doesn't work:

```
(
    ggplot(df, aes(y = 'values', x = after_stat('count'), fill = 'group'))
    + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)
)
#PlotnineError: 'stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.'
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coord_flip` to achieve the desired result:

```
from plotnine import *
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': np.random.normal(0,10,1000), 'group': ['a']*500 + ['b']*500})
# 
(
    ggplot(df, aes(x = 'values', y = after_stat('count'), fill = 'group'))
    + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)
    + coord_flip()
)
```

[image]